# Android: Save an ArrayList to file, then load it

Tags: java, android, file, arraylist

Sorry for my bad English, I speak French.

I've been trying to figure out how to do that for too long now, I have tried many different suggestions found on many different forums, but none of them have worked.

I have a class "Jeu" (means *game* in French), that creates a Jeu with 3 parameters (String nom, String age, String lieu).

I made an ArrayList with those games, in my "ListeJeux" class. The ArrayList "jeux" contains 10 Jeu.

I found a way for my application to show a listView of this ArrayList.
But if I want to be able to add more Jeu to it later, I need a way to save it.
I'm thinking about saving that ArrayList to a file, and making a "file to ArrayList" method and an "ArrayList to file" method.

But I don't know how, I've tried many things, none of them worked.
I'm a beginner with Java, and a *complete noob* with android development.

Thanks!

These are my classes:

Jeu:

```
package com.example.jouons;

public class Jeu{
    String nomDefaut = "Nom invalide";
    String ageDefaut = "Groupe d'age invalide";
    String lieuDefaut = "Lieu invalide";

    String nom = "";
    String age = "";
    String lieu = "";

    public Jeu(String nom, String age, String lieu) {
        if (validerParamJeu(nom) && validerParamJeu(age) && validerParamJeu(lieu)) {
            setNom(nom);
            setAge(age);
            setLieu(lieu);
        } else {
            setNom(nomDefaut);
            setAge(ageDefaut);
            setLieu(lieuDefaut);
        }
    }

    public String getNom() {
        return nom;
    }

    public void setNom(String nom) {
        if (validerParamJeu(nom))
            this.nom = nom;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        if (validerParamJeu(age))
            this.age = age;
    }

    public String getLieu() {
        return lieu;
    }

    public void setLieu(String lieu) {
        if (validerParamJeu(lieu))
            this.lieu = lieu;
    }

    private boolean validerParamJeu(String param) {
        return (param != null);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getNom();
    }   
}
```

ListeJeux:

```
package com.example.jouons;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListeJeux{ 
    static ArrayList<Jeu> jeux = new ArrayList<>();

    static ArrayList<Jeu> addJeu(){
        jeux.add(new Jeu("Ballon fou", "moyens grands", "intérieur"));
        jeux.add(new Jeu("Soccer", "petits moyens grands", "intérieur extérieur"));
        jeux.add(new Jeu("Stratégo", "grands", "extérieur"));
        jeux.add(new Jeu("Ballon fou", "moyens grands", "intérieur"));
        jeux.add(new Jeu("Soccer", "petits moyens grands", "intérieur extérieur"));
        jeux.add(new Jeu("Stratégo", "grands", "extérieur"));
        jeux.add(new Jeu("Ballon fou", "moyens grands", "intérieur"));
        jeux.add(new Jeu("Soccer", "petits moyens grands", "intérieur extérieur"));
        jeux.add(new Jeu("Stratégo", "grands", "extérieur"));
        jeux.add(new Jeu("Ballon fou", "moyens grands", "intérieur"));
        return jeux;
    }   
}
```

ListeActivity (The activity that shows the ArrayList):

```
package com.example.jouons;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;    
import java.util.ArrayList;    
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListeActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_liste);

        ListView jeuxListe = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewAnimals);

        if (ListeJeux.jeux != null) {
            ArrayAdapter<Jeu> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Jeu>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ListeJeux.addJeu());
            jeuxListe.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }

        Button retourButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnListeRetour);
        retourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.liste, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

My manifest (just in case you need it):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.jouons"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".RechercherActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_rechercher" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".TrouvezActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_trouvez" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_liste" >     
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: "But I don't know how, I've tried many things, none of them worked." - Please show us some of these things you've tried, and tell us how, exactly, they did not work.

Comment: You honestly couldn't find ANY examples of persisting data on Android by doing a google search?

Comment: I searched for "save object to file" mainly, I tried a couple of methods with serialization, but they didnt work, no crash, just no new file in my workspace.

Comment: Seriously, pick any android development book/guide, there will be a section on persisting data. Stack Overflow requires you to at least have done your due diligence in doing the appropriate amount of research

Comment: Ok, I'll go on a more noob-friendly forum, I considered 10h of tries/research enough...

Answer (score 0):

You can store each game as a set of strings in shared preferences. See [Shared Preferences Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). You would use your game objects getters and setters to move the strings to and from the shared prefs. These are key value pairs, so you could use a loop to assign an incrementing number as the key for each set you store. You should save this number so you can use it to step through all of your sets upon retrieval.